# Prevent addition of arrays with different shapes

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have realized recently that python can automatically add 2 arrays even if they have different dimensions, as long as one of the arrays contains the dimensions of the other. For example:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b=np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
print a.shape
print b.shape
b=b+a
print b
```

This behavior can give me some problems, as was expecting python to return an error if the shapes are not exactly the same.

Is there any way to turn of this behavior so the operation will fail if the shapes are not exactly the same?

Comment: Your code gives `SyntaxError` in line 3.

Comment: The term you are referring to is called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in `numpy`. Regarding your question, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789889/how-to-prevent-adding-two-arrays-by-broadcasting-in-numpy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to disable that behavior. It's called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) (and it's not as easy as "as long as one of the arrays contains the dimensions of the other"!) and built into NumPy.

However you can always compare the shapes of your arrays before doing any operations or use a custom subclass of `numpy.ndarray`.